# Code for titlepage

Tags: titles

I am trying to copy the style/fomat of the following titlepage, however I am struggling to create the huge space betwenn the top of the page and the first title. How would a code for the following titlpage look like, thanks for the help in advance!
[image]

Comment: `\vspace*{<amount>}` should work, if not, try to put `\null` before that.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.